# Removing json item causes error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a simple button that removes an item from a json object. This is currently working fine. The issue I have is that once it's clicked once it doesn't work again due to a js error. The error is reporting that an item is null.

I thought `delete` would remove the json item, not simply mark it as null.

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/715qkhwo/1)

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var jsonObj = $.parseJSON($('div').text());

  var name;

  if($(this).attr('id') == 'btn1') name = 'John2';
  if($(this).attr('id') == 'btn2') name = 'Anna';

  $.each(jsonObj, function(i, obj) {
    if (obj.firstName == 'Anna') delete jsonObj[i];
  });

  $('div').text(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
});
```

I need to get the json text from the div, remove an item from it, then save it as text back to the div. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id') === this.id`

Comment: @Alnitak not sure how that would help? but thanks https://jsfiddle.net/715qkhwo/3/

Comment: It won't "fix" anything, but using `$(this).attr('id')` instead of the trivial `this.id` is a common jQuery code smell

Answer (score 1):

1. you should be iterating over the `.employees` array element of the object
2. you can't delete an element from an array with `delete` - use `.splice` instead.
3. you should `return false` from the `$.each` callback once a match has been made, or you'll end up iterating over non-existent elements - you must always be careful when modifying the size of a collection whilst iterating over it.

See https://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/mjw4z7jL/1/

Comment: Thanks but hat doesn't seem to work either https://jsfiddle.net/715qkhwo/2/

Comment: what's that `delete` still doing there?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are removing items from the array while looping through the keys. When you remove an item, it will rearrange the other items depending on how the array is implemented internally, and you end up with a loop that doesn't iterate over the keys that you expect.
Use `for` loop instead of `$.each` or  `return false` once you are inside the condition.

```
 $("button").click(function() {
  var jsonObj = $.parseJSON($('div').text());

  var name;

  if($(this).attr('id') == 'btn1') name = 'John2';
  if($(this).attr('id') == 'btn2') name = 'Anna';
  for(i=0; i < jsonObj.employees.length; i++){
   if (jsonObj.employees[i].firstName == name){
        jsonObj.employees.splice(i,1);
    } 
  }

  $('div').text(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bipen/715qkhwo/4/

Remind you, this is not a proper solution and depends entirely on how your json object is. If there are two objects with same firstName, this might give you weird result. So make sure you add all of the needed condition before you delete it.

Comment: You should probably mention that this has the potential for failure if there are multiple employees with the same first name... when you splice the first one from the array, you will be skipping over the element if not re-indexed properly.

Comment: @DannyBuonocore yup.. thanks Added. Please feel free to edit the answer if there is anything you want to add.. :)

Answer (score -1):

You were iterating through the root object, it has one single property, employees

You needed to loop through object.employees array

Far easier with native array filter function

Note: This will handle multiple Johns and Annas without issue

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var jsonObj = $.parseJSON($('div').text());

  var name;

  if(this.id == 'btn1') name = 'John2';
  else if(this.id == 'btn2') name = 'Anna';
  else return;
  jsonObj.employees = jsonObj.employees.filter(function(emp) {
    return emp.firstName != name;
  })
  $('div').text(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/715qkhwo/5/

Comment: deleting *first* occurrence isn't necessarily correct